# javascript run function if everything is checked, filled, selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with javscript. I was wonder is it possible to create something like this in javascript:

```
<script>
function all_is_filled(){
if($('input[type=checkbox]').checked && document.getElementById('text_field').value!="" )
{
//do something...
}

}
</script>
```

So when someone check checkbox and fill text_field then this do something...Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your code as it is (except use `$('#text_field')` instead of `getElementById('text_field')` as you are using jQuery

Comment: I thought it will be something like that... I asked a question to see is there easier solution...thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
function all_is_filled() {
     if ($('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked') == true && $('#text_field').value != "") {
        //do something...
    }
};
$('#myform').on('change', function () {
    all_is_filled()
});
```

I added a listen function to call `all_is_filled()` on change, but you can also put it onsubmit.

Simple demo **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/KS8Ea/)**

Comment: @MrCkobe, post your html so I can adapt my answer to your ids/classes

Comment: I can't get `$('#myform').on('change', function () {
    all_is_filled()
});` to do anything

Comment: Add `$(document).ready(function() { // code here });` around the code. So it's called when the page has loaded. It can be the html has not loaded yet. Check your console for errors also.

Comment: @MrCkobe, nice to have 2 pair of eyes looking at problems. Easy to miss things :)